# Override global Python with local one on linux

Tags: linux, path

I have installed a python interpreter to a user-directory on a system where I do not have root-access. This system has an older version of Python already installed. I want to make my local installation the default for me. So basically, when I type `python`, instead of `/usr/bin/python` I want `~/MyPythonDir/python` to be invoked.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I have changed my `PATH` to look like this right after I log in:

```
echo $PATH
~/MyPythonDir:OtherPathStuff
```

`MyPythonDir` is the directory containing the python executable. However, when I type

```
which python
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Also, `MyPythonDir` contains `python2.7`, but when I try to execute that it says it cannot find it.

Comment: You should specify what shell you're using. Most people will assume Bash or `sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. In the setup-script (`.tcshrc`) I set the path using the tilde. When I replaced the tilde by the full path, it worked! Can anyone explain this?

Comment: can you show the exact line you used in .tcshrc?

Comment: The tilde is really only an interactive command line convenience. There are lots of places it won't get expanded. Use `$HOME` instead.

Comment: in scripts it usually does but it gets escaped by "" so `echo "$HOME"` and `echo ~` will expand but `echo "~"` will not.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.